# Javascript notification function

Tags: javascript, fonts, popupwindow, urdu

I've a website, in which an URDU font is used (named:Jameel Noori Nastaleeq). This font is not install by default in every PC or laptop. Now I want that, when a user come the URDU version of website. A script; which check that the font is install or not in {PC or laptop}(Only, not on other devices).If that font is install then OK, If not then give a notification to install that specific font for better view.

If it possible, then can you please help me?
thanks in advance.

Comment: notifier : https://jsfiddle.net/ot4y01zd/

Comment: is it available as a web font?

Comment: yes it is but its size is 14mb. that's why I can't make any webkit.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't allow you to access a list of fonts directly, however there are some tricks you can use to detect if a specific font is available.

These generally involve comparing the dimensions of a given block of text with two different fonts applied (default vs. custom). If the dimensions are the same then you can safely assume that your font is unavailable.

Libraries like [FontDetect](https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/FontDetect) will do all the hard work for you, allowing you to solve your problem in a few lines:

```
if (!FontDetect.isFontLoaded('Jameel Noori Nastaleeq')) {
    // Font isn't available - show your message here.
    alert("Get ready for a 14MB font download!")
}
```

Another consideration is to look into the [Noto font project](http://www.google.com/get/noto/#/), which is Google's attempt at creating an open source, international font library (available for embedding via Google Fonts).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that! All you need to do is to have a font's file on your server. Load it from css and then anyone can see that particular urdu font. You need to take a look at the CSS [`font-face`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) rule. Feel free to ask any questions in the comments section.

Comment: I've tried this but not working for me :(
The ttf file of font is about 14mb, is it possible that I can load it first before the website loads.

Comment: Yes, I think there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: let me try !
Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't embed a 14mb font file. It means every user who lands on your site will be forced to download it - very bad practice. Not only will the site take a long time to load, your layout will change once the font has loaded (search FOUT in google).